# Javascript - how to get the value of 2 dates from string?

Tags: javascript, date

Is  possible to find the value of 2 dates from string

For example: I have this string

"March 2 2017 - Aug 3 2019"

So how can I put the 2 date in different variables ?

Comment: Just about anything is possible. But, it is unclear what, exactly you want. Also, what have you tried? We're not a code writing service, you have to make an attempt at a solution and show us what you've done.

Comment: You're probably looking for [**`.split`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

if I understand you correctly you want something like this:

```
var dates = "March 2 2017 - Aug 3 2019".split(' - ');
var first = dates[0];
var second = dates[1];
console.log(first); // outputs March 2 2017
console.log(second); // outputs Aug 3 2019
```

Comment: Please don't provide answers to bad questions that shouldn't have been posted in the first place. It just encourages more of the same.

Comment: Yes, I couldn't understand how can I split the string and store the values in var's

Comment: @ScottMarcus is there a rule somewhere in Stack Exchange that addresses this, or any type of precedence for your comment? I worry that Markus' answer may have been downvoted simply because he answered - not because his answer was insufficient.

Comment: Its not a bad question because there is a long part to analyse the results and use them in different ways but to save your time I wrote it short because the solution easy but I was have some issues. Im sorry for that but I will try to explain my future questions more and I will put my codes

Comment: @DominicFox Yes, his answer was down voted simply because he answered. That is common with answers that shouldn't have been posted in the first place. Is there precedence for my comment, yes, it's quite common knowledge for people that are very active on the site. Is there a "rule" about it? Well, no, but there are guidelines about what makes a [good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Within that last link, there is guidance that says: **"Answer well-asked questions"** - this is ***not*** one of those.

Comment: I think people need to remember that all developers start out as novices and there is no harm in people approaching us for help. To state there is no right to ask questions like this comes across as a little stuck up in my own opinion, there is always room for people to learn and progress and sometimes they need to ask more experienced developers

Confused, you have said the same person answered the question but I see 2 different IDs for the OP and the answered question

Comment: @User1538 No, it's not [a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @DataCure—the OP's requirements can be clarified through comments and the question updated. That way they learn javascript and how to ask questions. ;-)

Comment: @DataCure It's not "stuck up". The site has guidelines for how to ask and answer questions (I've provided those links in the above comments). To keep the quality of the site high, we simply ask people to follow the guidelines. This is a community and we're all given the tools to help others to work together to keep the quality of the site up.

Comment: @ScottMarcus good response, thanks for increasing my SO knowledge. What do you say to the fact that this question could be edited to become a "good question?" If it were, then the answer could become a "good answer" and the downvote would be erroneous. I'm not trying to argue, just trying to understand the redundancies that this community has given itself.

Comment: @DominicFox That could happen and typically when it does, the down votes are removed.